# Is it okay to have a callback function in a javascript if statement

Tags: javascript, callback

This may seem a bit dirty this code but i am just wondering if it is actually okay. Or maybe it should be avoided.

```
        let cb = (valid) => {
            if(valid){
                console.log('hi')
            }
        }
        if(typeof this.validate === "undefined" || this.validate(cb)){
            console.log('hi')
        }
```

because the log output will still only fire once. But maybe this method is not a good idea?

Comment: Seems perfectly fine as long as said `if` conditions aren't *too* long, though this example seems a bit minimal and contrived (do you have an uglier example?) Might be more suited for codereview than SO though

Comment: @CertainPerformance Might be a little too minimal for CR, so it doesn't really fit any SE site.

Comment: You could shorten it to `if(!this.validate || this.validate(cb)) { ... }`

Comment: Lets agree on that if he already uses `typeof`, he could at least check for `!== "function"`. Whether `!this.validate` is enough depends on other factors.

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten the condition to:

```
if(!this.validate || this.validate(cb)) { 
    // ...
}
```

Since your question is about style / generally accepted practises in JavaScript, this is not considered bad code. That is subjective of course, but this is not unusual to see and it accomplishes the intended function without being too confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Nice question.

There are 2 answers to your question, depending upon callback function behavior.

First why callbacks? Callbacks are used to perform different operations by same function under different use case. Example after getting result sometime need to display it, sometime need to insert it into database. Our function work is to just get result and pass it to callback function for further process.

Now answer to your question:

1. Yes, it is okay to use callback in `if` condition. This is okay if callback is a synchronous function. As under this condition we want our function to pass `if` condition under different circumstances, for example:

   Let two functions `sumOdd` and `sumEven`, both these function are synchronous and `sumOdd` return sum of two numbers if sum of two number is odd else return `false/0`, similarly `sumEven` for even sum of two numbers.

Code:

```
function sumOdd(a,b) {
    if ( (a+b)%2 === 0 || typeof a !== 'number' || typeof b !== 'number') return false;

    return a+b;
}

function sumEven(a,b) {
    if ( (a+b)%2 !== 0 || typeof a !== 'number' || typeof b !== 'number') return false;

    return a+b;
}

function main(cb) {
    // let x, y be two random generated numbers of input from user
    let x, y;

    // after some operation let main call callback function
    // main function don't care about what callback function do just its working is over.
    return cb(x, y);
}

// Depending upon our requirement if we want to check for odd sum pass sumOdd as callback
if ( main(sumOdd) ) {
    // This works for odd sum
}
if ( main(sumEven) ) {
    // This works for even sum
}
```

Using callback in above example is good to have, as both the callbacks are synchronous function and saves writing two function for `main` function just to call 2 different function and rest all functionality is same.

2. No, it's not okay to use callback in `if` conditions, as most of the callback functions are used if calling function is asynchronous function and most of the javascript callback functions are calling another function to send back response.

   Example promise, API calls, database calls, express `get`, `post` and other functions, all calls another function to send back response.

```

```
new Promise ( (resolve, reject) => {
    resolve('something'); // This is again calling a function
    reject('something');  // Reject is also a function
});

app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    res.send('something')    // res.send, res.json, res.end, res.write are all functions to send back response.
});
```

```

To summarize, it's okay to use if callbacks are synchronous and all your code is synchronous in `if` condition. Not if there's any case of callback hell or asynchronous functions.

Would suggest you to avoid such case as might result in `callback hell` if not maintained properly.